# WebBrowser - How to type into that textbox

Tags: .net, vb.net

I'm trying to type into a textbox with the following HTML code:

```
<input id="textfield-1091-inputEl" type="password" size="1" name="textfield-1091-inputEl" class="x-form-field x-form-text" autocomplete="off" aria-invalid="false" data-errorqtip="" style="width: 100%; height: 32px;">
```

I tried to use the following code:

```
    For Each Element As HtmlElement In WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("input")
        If Element.OuterHtml.Contains("textfield-1091-inputEl") Then
            Element.SetAttribute("value", "texttttttt")
            Return
        End If
    Next
```

and:

```
    For Each Element As HtmlElement In WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("input")
        If Element.Id.Contains("textfield-1091-inputEl") Then
            Element.SetAttribute("value", "texttttttt")
            Return
        End If
    Next
```

and:

```
WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("textfield-1091-inputEl").SetAttribute("value", "texttttttt")
```

But unfortunately I got no results.
Full code:

```html
<div class="x-panel setPwd x-box-item x-window-item x-panel-default" style="margin: 0px; height: 145px; right: auto; left: 40px; width: 571px; top: 247px;" id="ext-comp-1090"><div id="ext-comp-1090-body" class="x-panel-body x-panel-body-default x-box-layout-ct x-panel-body-default" style="height: 145px; width: 571px; left: 0px; top: 0px;"><div id="ext-comp-1090-innerCt" class="x-box-inner " role="presentation" style="height: 145px; width: 445px;"><div id="ext-comp-1090-targetEl" class="x-box-target" style="width: 445px;"><div class="x-panel x-box-item x-panel-default" id="panel-1102" style="right: auto; left: 0px; top: 0px; margin: 0px; height: 156px; width: 445px;"><div id="panel-1102-body" class="x-panel-body x-panel-body-default x-box-layout-ct x-panel-body-default" style="left: 0px; top: 0px; width: 445px; height: 156px;"><div id="panel-1102-innerCt" class="x-box-inner " role="presentation" style="width: 445px; height: 156px;"><div id="panel-1102-targetEl" class="x-box-target" style="width: 445px;"><div class="x-panel x-box-item x-panel-default" style="width: 445px; right: auto; left: 0px; top: 0px; margin: 0px; height: 156px;" id="panel-1103"><div id="panel-1103-body" class="x-panel-body x-panel-body-default x-box-layout-ct x-panel-body-default" style="width: 445px; left: 0px; top: 0px; height: 156px;"><div id="panel-1103-innerCt" class="x-box-inner " role="presentation" style="height: 156px; width: 445px;"><div id="panel-1103-targetEl" class="x-box-target" style="width: 445px;"><table class="undefined align-left x-table-plain x-form-item x-form-type-password x-box-item -default x-vbox-form-item" style="width: 440px; height: 32px; table-layout: fixed; right: auto; left: 0px; top: 0px; margin: 0px;" cellpadding="0" id="textfield-1091"><tbody><tr role="presentation" id="textfield-1091-inputRow" class="x-form-item-input-row"><td role="presentation" id="textfield-1091-labelCell" style="" valign="top" halign="left" width="185" class="x-field-label-cell"><label id="textfield-1091-labelEl" for="textfield-1091-inputEl" class="x-form-item-label textlabel x-unselectable textlabel-left cuttitle" style="width:180px;margin-right:5px;" unselectable="on" title=""><span t="sys.OldPwd" id="ext-gen1335">Old Password</span></label></td><td role="presentation" class="x-form-item-body  " id="textfield-1091-bodyEl" colspan="2" style="width: 100%;"><input id="textfield-1091-inputEl" type="password" size="1" name="textfield-1091-inputEl" class="x-form-field x-form-text" autocomplete="off" aria-invalid="false" data-errorqtip="" style="width: 100%; height: 32px;"></td></tr></tbody></table><div class="x-panel x-box-item x-panel-default" style="margin: 0px; right: auto; left: 0px; top: 47px; height: 99px; width: 445px;" id="ext-comp-1092"><div id="ext-comp-1092-body" class="x-panel-body x-panel-body-default x-box-layout-ct x-panel-body-default" style="left: 0px; top: 0px; width: 445px; height: 99px;"><div id="ext-comp-1092-innerCt" class="x-box-inner " role="presentation" style="height: 99px; width: 445px;"><div id="ext-comp-1092-targetEl" class="x-box-target" style="width: 445px;"><div class="x-panel x-box-item x-panel-default" id="panel-1098" style="right: auto; left: 0px; top: 0px; margin: 0px; height: 99px; width: 445px;"><div id="panel-1098-body" class="x-panel-body x-panel-body-default x-box-layout-ct x-panel-body-default" style="left: 0px; top: 0px; width: 445px; height: 99px;"><div id="panel-1098-innerCt" class="x-box-inner " role="presentation" style="width: 445px; height: 99px;"><div id="panel-1098-targetEl" class="x-box-target" style="width: 445px;"><div class="x-panel x-box-item x-panel-default" style="width: 445px; right: auto; left: 0px; top: 0px; margin: 0px; height: 99px;" id="panel-1099"><div id="panel-1099-body" class="x-panel-body x-panel-body-default x-box-layout-ct x-panel-body-default" style="width: 445px; left: 0px; top: 0px; height: 99px;"><div id="panel-1099-innerCt" class="x-box-inner " role="presentation" style="height: 99px; width: 445px;"><div id="panel-1099-targetEl" class="x-box-target" style="width: 445px;"><div class="x-panel x-box-item x-panel-default" id="panel-1100" style="right: auto; left: 0px; top: 0px; margin: 0px; height: 42px; width: 445px;"><div id="panel-1100-body" class="x-panel-body x-panel-body-default x-panel-body-default" style="left: 0px; top: 0px; width: 445px; height: 42px;"><span id="panel-1100-outerCt" style="display:table;"><div id="panel-1100-innerCt" style="height: 100%; vertical-align: top; display: table-cell;" class=""><table class="undefined align-left x-table-plain x-form-item x-form-type-password -default x-autocontainer-form-item x-form-invalid" style="width: 440px; height: 32px; table-layout: fixed;" cellpadding="0" id="textfield-1096"><tbody><tr role="presentation" id="textfield-1096-inputRow" class="x-form-item-input-row"><td role="presentation" id="textfield-1096-labelCell" style="" valign="top" halign="left" width="185" class="x-field-label-cell"><label id="textfield-1096-labelEl" for="textfield-1096-inputEl" class="x-form-item-label textlabel x-unselectable textlabel-left cuttitle" style="width:180px;margin-right:5px;" unselectable="on" title=""><span t="sys.NewPwd" id="ext-gen1336">New Password</span></label></td><td role="presentation" class="x-form-item-body  " id="textfield-1096-bodyEl" colspan="2" style="width: 100%;"><input id="textfield-1096-inputEl" type="password" size="1" name="textfield-1096-inputEl" class="x-form-field x-form-required-field x-form-text x-form-invalid-field" autocomplete="off" aria-invalid="true" data-errorqtip="<ul class=&quot;x-list-plain&quot;><li role=&quot;alert&quot;><span t=&quot;com.NullPwdTip&quot;>Password cannot be null.</span></li></ul>" style="width: 100%; height: 32px;"></td></tr></tbody></table><div class="x-panel showLevel x-panel-default" style="width: 260px; height: 5px;" id="panel-1101"><div id="panel-1101-body" class="x-panel-body x-panel-body-default x-panel-body-default" style="width: 260px; left: 0px; top: 0px; height: 5px;"><span id="panel-1101-outerCt" style="display: table; width: 100%; table-layout: fixed;"><div id="panel-1101-innerCt" style="display:table-cell;height:100%;vertical-align:top;" class=""><div class="x-panel x-panel-default" id="pwdlevel" style="height: 5px;"><div id="pwdlevel-body" class="x-panel-body x-panel-body-default x-box-layout-ct x-panel-body-default" style="left: 0px; top: 0px; width: 260px; height: 5px;"><div id="pwdlevel-innerCt" class="x-box-inner " role="presentation" style="width: 260px; height: 5px;"><div id="pwdlevel-targetEl" class="x-box-target" style="width: 260px;"><div class=" pwd_defaultCls x-box-item -default" style="height: 5px; right: auto; left: 0px; top: 0px; margin: 0px; width: 83px;" id="panel-1093"><div id="panel-1093-body" class="-body -body-default -body-default" style="height: 5px; width: 83px; left: 0px; top: 0px;"><span id="panel-1093-outerCt" style="display: table; width: 100%; table-layout: fixed; height: 100%;"><div id="panel-1093-innerCt" style="display:table-cell;height:100%;vertical-align:top;" class=""></div></span></div></div><div class=" pwd_defaultCls x-box-item -default" style="height: 5px; right: auto; left: 86px; top: 0px; margin: 0px; width: 84px;" id="panel-1094"><div id="panel-1094-body" class="-body -body-default -body-default" style="height: 5px; width: 84px; left: 0px; top: 0px;"><span id="panel-1094-outerCt" style="display: table; width: 100%; table-layout: fixed; height: 100%;"><div id="panel-1094-innerCt" style="display:table-cell;height:100%;vertical-align:top;" class=""></div></span></div></div><div class=" pwd_defaultCls x-box-item -default" style="height: 5px; right: auto; left: 173px; top: 0px; margin: 0px; width: 84px;" id="panel-1095"><div id="panel-1095-body" class="-body -body-default -body-default" style="height: 5px; width: 84px; left: 0px; top: 0px;"><span id="panel-1095-outerCt" style="display: table; width: 100%; table-layout: fixed; height: 100%;"><div id="panel-1095-innerCt" style="display:table-cell;height:100%;vertical-align:top;" class=""></div></span></div></div></div></div></div></div></div></span></div></div></div></span></div></div><table class="undefined align-left x-table-plain x-form-item x-form-type-password x-box-item -default x-vbox-form-item" style="width: 440px; height: 32px; table-layout: fixed; right: auto; left: 0px; top: 52px; margin: 0px;" cellpadding="0" id="textfield-1097"><tbody><tr role="presentation" id="textfield-1097-inputRow" class="x-form-item-input-row"><td role="presentation" id="textfield-1097-labelCell" style="" valign="top" halign="left" width="185" class="x-field-label-cell"><label id="textfield-1097-labelEl" for="textfield-1097-inputEl" class="x-form-item-label textlabel x-unselectable textlabel-left cuttitle" style="width:180px;margin-right:5px;" unselectable="on" title=""><span t="sys.Pwdconfirm" id="ext-gen1337">Confirm Password</span></label></td><td role="presentation" class="x-form-item-body  " id="textfield-1097-bodyEl" colspan="2" style="width: 100%;"><input id="textfield-1097-inputEl" type="password" size="1" name="textfield-1097-inputEl" class="x-form-field x-form-text" autocomplete="off" aria-invalid="false" data-errorqtip="" style="width: 100%; height: 32px;"></td></tr></tbody></table></div></div></div></div></div></div></div></div></div></div></div></div></div></div></div></div></div></div></div></div></div></div></div></div>
```

Comment: *When* is that code executed? Show the full procedure. -- You should also add a tag that specifies the GUI platform in use.

Comment: @Jimi the code is executed by a button click event

Comment: That would be a strange password textbox, as the `size="1"` attribute restricts the text to **one** character.

Comment: @HelO'Ween but it's not, if I manually type, I can enter a longer password

Comment: Added full code to the main post

Comment: With `dim element = WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("textfield-1091-inputEl") if element isnot nothing then element.SetAttribute("value", "texttttttt")`, the value is set. Using the HTML you have posted here. -- Your complete code and the platform TAG are still missing.

Comment: It does not works.

Comment: Yes, it does. Take the HTML you have posted, slap it in a `.html` file. load it in a WebBrowser and run that code after. If it doesn't work in your real use case, it's because you haven't provided the correct information. How did you know what is the ID of that element? Did you navigate to an address using a different Browser (e.g., Chrome, FireFox), got the ID from there and the navigated to the same URL with a WebBrowser Control? -- Why aren't you posting your code, with enough context to understand what you're working with? -- The GUI platform is still missing

Comment: I tried to post the code of the whole page, including HTML, CSS, JS, but it does not works correctly, and it does contains too much characters. It's an administration interface of a local device, so I don't know what other informations could I post and how.

Comment: The full HTML is not needed. Answer the questions I've asked in my previous comment: how did you get the ID of that element? Did you debug your code? When debugging, did you inspect the content of the WebBrowser text, to verify that the same element with the same ID exists? etc. -- Did you make the test I've suggested (create a `.html` file, paste inside the HTML you have posted, load that file in the WebBrowser and run that code)? -- The GUI Platform TAG is still missing.